# local variable 'trip' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I have this snippet

```
form = TripManagementForm(request.POST)
alert=dict()
if form.is_valid():
    trip_id = form.cleaned_data['trip_id']
    trip = Trip.objects.get(pk=trip_id)
    trip.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    trip.advance_payed = form.cleaned_data['advance']
    trip.rent = form.cleaned_data['rent']
    trip.toll_fee = form.cleaned_data['toll_fee']
    trip.checkpost_charges = form.cleaned_data['checkpost']
    trip.police_checking = form.cleaned_data['police_checking']
    trip.accidents_renumeration = form.cleaned_data['accidents_renumeration']
    trip.fuel_expense = form.cleaned_data['fuel_expense']
    trip.maintainance.trip_maintainance = form.cleaned_data['maintainance']
    trip.driver = form.cleaned_data['driver']
    trip.payment_status = form.cleaned_data['payment_status']
    if not form.cleaned_data['payment_mode'] == 0:
        trip.payment_mode = form.cleaned_data['payment_mode']
    trip.cheque_no = form.cleaned_data['cheque_no']
    trip.bata = form.cleaned_data['bata']
    trip.others = form.cleaned_data['others']
    trip.setbalance()
    trip.save()
    alert['success'] = 'Saved successfully'
    context = dict(context.items() + ({'form':form, 'trip': trip, 'alert': alert}).items())
    return render_to_response('portal_trip_management.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    trip_id = form.data['trip_id']
    trip = Trip.objects.get(pk=trip_id)
    alert['error'] = 'Encountered some error'
    context = dict(context.items() + ({'form':form, 'trip': trip, 'alert':alert}).items())
    return render_to_response('portal_trip_management.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And I'm getting the error

```
local variable 'trip' referenced before assignment
```

Well it is showing on the return statement just after `alert['success'] = 'Saved successfully'`. Cant find out what's going on. I have already referenced trip before. Still it is showing up the error. Please help out. I saw similar questions in stackoverflow but again none of the solution works out.

**EDIT** Adding the Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://beta.track24.in/management/tripdetails?trip_id=3

Django Version: 1.4.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'accounts',
 'managements',
 'locations')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/track24/managements/views.py" in trip_management
  443.          return render_to_response('portal_trip_management.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /management/tripdetails
Exception Value: local variable 'trip' referenced before assignment
```

And here is the details of the POST request

```
advance                 u'0.00'
maintainance            u'0.00'
toll_fee                u'0.00'
bata                    u'200.00'
payment_status          u'on'
driver                  u'1'
checkpost               u'0.00'
rent                    u'0.00'
others                  u'0.00'
payment_mode            u'check'
csrfmiddlewaretoken     u'PMBlzlrNRUyiWH9UzJIrONsDRNU2MOhj'
trip_id                 u'3'
accidents_renumeration  u'0.00'
police_checking         u'100.00'
fuel_expense            u'0.00'
```

Comment: Silly question - but does that Trip Query return anything? You don't seem to check whether it actually returned a result.

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace please?

Comment: ya the trip query returns i guess. well I'll update the stacktrace in the question

Comment: Your current code won't throw that exception, but you could have an error in your indentation (mixing tabs and spaces would do that). Run your `manage.py` script with `python -tt` to detect any inconsistencies, and fix those first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not understand on how to use the python tt. And again I'm using Pydev so i guess the mixed tabs are not the problem. If so pydev would have warnings and in this case it did not shoot any.

Comment: Does your `portal_trip_management.html` template refer to `trip`?

Comment: Another option is that your traceback is pointing to the wrong location because your  source code changed but your server did not reload it. Restart the Django server and retry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help. Just did a server restart things worked magically. I had tried this before posting it here. Then it did not work though